# API return Object Promise and I don't know how to use it

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need and API that returns a string, but it returns an Object Promise, and I don't understand and know what to do. Here's my piece of code. Thank you very much.

This is the API

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../dbconn.php';
    
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $query = "SELECT sal FROM usuarios WHERE (usuario = '$usuario' OR email = '$usuario')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row[0];
    $request .= $row[0]; // Concatenamos la contraseña introducida con la sal
    $request = hash('sha512', $request);

    return $request;
```

This is the JS code:

```
contrasena = document.getElementById("InputPasswordSignup").value.trim();
        if (contrasena != ""){
            contrasena = hashContrasena(contrasena);
            alert(contrasena);
            sql = sql.concat(" contraseña = '", contrasena).concat("',");
        }

async function hashContrasena(pass){
    res = await fetch('/api/hash_input.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: pass
    })
    res = await res.text();
    /*if (res != 'success') {
        alert(res);
    }else{
        alert("Actualización realizada con éxito");
        window.location.reload();
    }*/
    return res;
}
```

Comment: When you call hashContrasena, it returns a Promise because it's an async function. To get the actual value (the string you're expecting), you need to wait for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: thanks!! and how do I do it? I'm completely lost, thanks in advance

Comment: you can try along the lines of `hashContrasena(pwd).then(callback)`

Comment: It's a callback mechanism. Once the promise resolves, the appropriate handler function is called. Google the term "thenable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, to get the actual value, you need to wait for the Promise to resolve in your Javascript, like this

```
contrasena = document.getElementById("InputPasswordSignup").value.trim();
if (contrasena != ""){
    hashContrasena(contrasena).then(hashedPassword => {
        alert(hashedPassword);
        sql = sql.concat(" contraseña = '", hashedPassword).concat("',");
        // Add your other code here
    });
}

async function hashContrasena(pass){
    let res = await fetch('/api/hash_input.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: pass
    });
    let hashedPassword = await res.text();
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

Comment: and how do I store the hashedPassword outside the {}? I need to return the sql variable but when returning it hasn't updated

Comment: To use the hashedPassword outside of the .then() block, you can define a variable in a higher scope and assign the hashedPassword to it. However, you need to remember that due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, you can't immediately use the value outside of the .then() block or the async function because it won't be set until the promise resolves.